# compile darknet-master return no Stb_INCLUDE_DIR error

Tags: darknet

I try to compile darknet-master and received this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Stb (missing: Stb_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindStb.cmake:29 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What is that Stb for? And how to fixed this? Stb_INCLUDE_DIR?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur if you use CMakeList.txt instead of Makefile for the compilation process. This is reasonable if you are cross-compiling and must use CMake, but in all other cases, you would use the Makefile in unix or the sln file prepared in Windows. In order to address this issue I have prepared a workaround, Please comment the below line in CMakeList.txt

```
find_package(Stb REQUIRED)
```

and after that add the below line

```
set(Stb_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdparty/stb/include)
```

Please note that the `stb` files are part of the source code.